# Using Table Decorators on Big Query Web Interface

Tags: google-bigquery

I saw the news about [Table Decorators](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#tabledecorators) being available to limit the amount of data that is queried by specifying a time interval or limit.  I did not see any examples on how to use the Table Decorators in the Big Query UI.  Below is an example query that I'd like to run and only look at data that came in over the last 4hours.  Any tips on how I can modify this query to utilize Table Decorators?

`SELECT 
    foo,
    count(*)
FROM [bigtable.201309010000]
GROUP BY 1`

**EDIT after trying example below**

The first query above scans 180GB of data for the month of September (up through Sept 19th).  I'd expect the query below to only scan data that came in during the time period specified.  In this case 4hrs, so I'd expect the billing to be about 1.6GB not 180GB.  Is there a way to set up ETL/query so we do not get billed for scanning the whole table?

`SELECT 
    foo,
    count(*)
FROM [bigtable.201309010000@-14400000]
GROUP BY 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use table decorators, you can either specify @timestamp or @timestamp-end_time. Timestamp can be negative, in which case it is relative; end_time can be empty, in which case it is the current time. You can use both of these special cases together, to get a time range relative to now. e.g. [table@-time_in_ms-]. So for your case, since 4 hours is 14400000 milliseconds, you can use:

```
SELECT foo, count(*) FROM [dataset.table@-14400000-] GROUP BY 1
```

This is a little bit confusing, we're intending to publish better documentation and examples soon.

Comment: Excellent.  One other question, is there a way to determine the latest time a table was updated within a dataset?  I'm looking at doing a Big Query to Big Query ETL, and I'd like to make sure the query on the base table is picking up all new data since the last ETL, but not picking up data already added to the result table.

Comment: Okay, I tried out the Table Decorator suggestion above and it seemed to work great, however, the amount of data my query touches is still the same.  I have a constant stream of data coming into a table partitioned on a monthly basis.  Is it possible to only query (get billed) for the data I'm interested in the last 4hours?

Comment: Regarding how to determine the last time a table was updated, if you call the tables.get() method, it wlll have a lastModifiedTime (see https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/Table.html#getLastModifiedTime())

Comment: Hmm... if the amount of data it touches is the same, that is a bug. Do you have a job id for a query that you expected to touch less data than it actually did?

Comment: Jordan, I just executed the query again to confirm the problem, and I did confirm the query scanned the same number of bytes with and without the decorator.  Here is the job id - job_6dfd109fe8fc4f7a83b7bd2e67ec004a.  Just a side note, the query with and without the decorator scans 2.3GB.

Comment: I realized that I was outfoxed by my own feature :-(. I've updated the answer with the correct incantation.